# LSI SAS BIOS Pred Fail

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

So, Today I installed 2 new drives in my server, and the LSI SAS BIOS is stating `Pred Fail Yes`. What could I do about this, and what does `Pred Fail Yes` Mean? We need the server for backups, and we needed the extra 2 drives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means Predictive Failure and it's taken from hdd's SMART readings

At least one of the SMART values for the hdd's marked as Pred Fail has reached the warning threshold, at which point you should no longer use that hdd, but replace ASAP.

Comment: Is there a way to get the drive to survive a _little_ longer?

Comment: No drive good or failing can be predicted how much will live. Many drives just die without warning. All you can do is normal care, no shocks, no overheat, no excessive/unneeded random I/O

Comment: Hmm... If I destroy the RAID 0 array, the S.M.A.R.T. status returns to normal. Weird...